# Current Record ID in Lightning exp page load

Tags: visualforce, lightning-aura-components, lightning-experience, inline-visualforce

I am using a VF page inlined in the page layout. but since org is lightning enabled i want current record id of the record loaded in lightning experience though I have tried `System.currentPageReference().getParameters().get('id')` but this is not working in lightning experience.

Any suggestions helps are appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

I don't seem to have a problem accessing the ID parameter from the URL in the case of an inline VF page in LEX. But I think you are not using the correct reference. I have not seen what you suggest. I usually use the following, which correctly returns the Id value in my test:

```
ApexPages.currentPage().getParameters().get('id')
```

To make a page inline, you should also have an instance of Standard Controller to work with.

An alternative could then be using a handle to that such as this:

```
public class MyExtensionClass

  private ApexPages.StandardController theController; 

  public MyExtensionClass(ApexPages.StandardController ctrl){
    this.theController = ctrl;
  }

  public MyObject__c getMyObject(){
    return [SELECT Id, Name FROM MyObject__c where id = theController.getId()];
  }
```

In general, I have always preferred this as a way to get the record ID of a page where I'm using the `StandardController + Extension` structure.

I did test the `System.currentPageReference()...` way you used, and that also works. Which leads me to believe that something else is going on for you.